# Local Nginx Ingress Controller In Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, minikube

I'm running this in minikube and I've already ran `minikube addons enable ingress`. My goal is to be able to see my homepage which is a react app at localhost:1234. Thanks for any help!
Here is my yaml for the nginx-ingress-controller:

```yaml
# nginx-ingress-controller.yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-ingress-controller
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress-controller
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx-ingress-controller
          image: k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.0.0
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --publish-service=kube-system/nginx-ingress-controller
            - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
            - --ingress-class=nginx
            - --http-port=1234  # Listen on port 1234
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "100m"  # Request 0.1 CPU cores
              memory: "128Mi"  # Request 128 megabytes of memory
            limits:
              cpu: "200m"  # Limit to 0.2 CPU cores
              memory: "256Mi"  # Limit to 256 megabytes of memory
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 1234  # Container port 1234
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 1234
      targetPort: 1234
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress-controller
```

My logs look like this:

I0308 00:47:57.537982       7 main.go:104] "SSL fake certificate created" file="/etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem"
F0308 00:47:57.539819       7 main.go:123] Unexpected error obtaining ingress-nginx pod: unable to get POD information (missing POD_NAME or POD_NAMESPACE environment variable

I do have an ingress that I'm hoping will be accessible to localhost:1234

```yaml
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: homepage
  namespace: bezier
  uid: 5ebcc3da-159c-4308-84e0-1a534aaf9229
  resourceVersion: '12242'
  generation: 1
  creationTimestamp: '2024-03-08T00:14:45Z'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: homepage
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: homepage
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.1.0
    helm.sh/chart: homepage-0.1.0
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: homepage
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: bezier
  managedFields:
    - manager: helm
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
      time: '2024-03-08T00:14:45Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:meta.helm.sh/release-name: {}
            f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: {}
          f:labels:
            .: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/instance: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/name: {}
            f:app.kubernetes.io/version: {}
            f:helm.sh/chart: {}
        f:spec:
          f:rules: {}
    - manager: nginx-ingress-controller
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
      time: '2024-03-08T00:43:54Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:status:
          f:loadBalancer:
            f:ingress: {}
      subresource: status
spec:
  rules:
    - host: localhost
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: homepage
                port:
                  number: 1234
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: 192.168.49.2
```

Comment: Check If the certificate is valid and secrets updated and as per this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59774299/nginx-ingress-controller-logs-keeps-telling-me-that-i-have-wrong-pod-information) you need to add env of pod, once updated and let me know if this helps.

Comment: Did you checked my comments is it helped to resolve your issue.